# Android map v2 not running after some months

Tags: android, google-api, android-maps-v2

I just developed Android map using map v2, api key was activated in Jul 16 of this year. Map was working fine, but now from the start of this month map is not showing anything, 
Another api key for map v2 for test project was created on Aug of this year and thats not working too.

Last time when i exported the APk, map was running fine but now same apk not showing map.

I didn't read anything about expiration of map api key. Any help? Thanks

Comment: I too have used and Developed map V2 few days before It's working fine have you declare  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> into your manifest

Comment: yes, everything was working from jul to last month, but its not workikng now. I didn't change anything, even i am not running the code, i am running the apk on the devices, on same device it was running fine. I tried to run on other device but now map is blank.

Comment: may be your problem be similar like here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717273/google-map-api-v2-is-not-showing-map-on-device

Comment: i dont think so, because map was working, its about key. I got two answers, i am trying to sort out. by the way thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes. I solved.problem was because i used debug/test API key instead of a release API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested my app, which is on the Play Store and uses a Google Maps v2 API key, and it is working for me as of 5 minutes ago. Maybe you're using a debug/test API key instead of a release API key? I remember the debug one only working for local testing and not for installs from the Play Store, so that might be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because your no of requests to the server is finished. Please check google documents for that.